Wifi icon and settings missing after installing Elementary OS 7.1
I have installed Elementary OS 7.1 on ASUS Vivobook and the installation process was successfully completed.
After logging into the system, the WIFI icon was not found (Only the airplane mode) as shown in the picture below:

I updated all the packages and upgraded everything, but seems like nothing fixed the issue.

Any solution for this problem !!
Thank you
